# Stopping an objects rotation during a spherecast

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Building an RTS building placement system in Unity and I have run into a small problem. I am using the mouseposition and a sphere cast in a state machine to place buildings. When in the "Placing" state, the building prefab follows the mouse position until the player clicks the left mouse button to place the building. If the player is then placing another building, i am using colliders on the already placed building to detect if a building is already there and turning the placing building to red color (for testing purposes). The issue i have run into is the building that is being placed rotates around the building it collides with, and moves over the top of it. How do i stop rotation and y axis movement on an object that is part of a mouse position raycast? I have already tried to constrain movement and rotation in the inspector on the RigidBody, i have tried completely moving the RigidBody altogther, and cant quite figure it out. Would it work if i set the y position and the rotation of the placing object at start and then if the rotation changes or the y position changes, set it back to the starting values? Or is there an easier way to do it?

Neil

```
 private void MoveCurrentPlaceableObjectToMouse()
{
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit hitInfo;

    if(Physics.SphereCast(ray, 2f, out hitInfo))
    {
        if (hitInfo.collider.tag == "Building")
        {
            isOkayToBuild = false;
            currentPlaceableObject.GetComponentInChildren<MeshRenderer>().material.color = Color.red;
        }
        else
        {
            isOkayToBuild = true;
            currentPlaceableObject.GetComponentInChildren<MeshRenderer>().material.color = Color.white;
        }

        currentPlaceableObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider>().isTrigger = false;
        state = BuildingState.Placing;
        currentPlaceableObject.transform.position = hitInfo.point;
        currentPlaceableObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.up, hitInfo.normal);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add the code you are currently using related to placing/moving the objects? Its quite hard for us to come with a solution if we don't know what you're doing exactly

Comment: Hi @Remy yes of course i can. Thank you kindly. added

Comment: Its important to note that because of the isOkayToBuild bool, the player cannot place the buildingToPlace ontop of or near another building so the functionality is there. I just dont like how it rotates around the collider of the building on the ground.